# Detecting a "skewed" image via FFT2

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I have the following distorted image which I've computed by reshaping the image to have one more row and one less column than it's supposed to.

```
nr = true_nr+1
nc = true_nc-1
img = stream[:nr*nc].reshape((nr, nc, 3))

from skimage.color import rgb2gray
dark_image_grey = rgb2gray(img)
```

[image]

Here is its resulting FFT2 transform:

```
dark_image_grey_fourier = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(dark_image_grey)) 
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
fft_image = np.log(abs(dark_image_grey_fourier))
plt.imshow(fft_image, cmap='gray');
```

[image]

Notice above that because of the diagonal skew of the image, the lighter regions of the fourier spectrum run at a 45 degree angle to the x/y frequency axes.

I'm trying to figure out how to estimate that this is indeed skewed, compared to the FFT2 for the undistorted image:

[image]

One thought I had was to fit a isotropic 2D Gaussian to the data, centered at the center pixel, and then examine the 2D covariance matrix to see if the off-diagonal terms are non-zero. But I'm not sure if there is a more elegant solution that is admitted by the Fourier transform itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you could try computing the autocorrelation between adjacent rows (for instance row_1 with row_2) then detecting the maximum peak and finally averaging for all lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2D [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (PCA) on the 2D FFT data to figure out how much the image is skewed and in which direction.

PCA is normally applied to a collection of points.  To apply it to your FFT data, consider the energy of each bit to be point density, i.e., consider a bin (fx,fy) with energy E to represent E points at position (fx,fy).